# How can I reduce the memory cost of this parallel table?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

### **The main question**

I was trying to obtain the piecewise cubic-spline interpolating polynomials of a series of very long lists of (x, f(x)) pairs (O(100) of them with length ~350,000), *i.e.* to get InterpolatingPolynomial on tab[[1;;4]], tab[[2;;5]], ..., with tab[[i]]={xi,yi}. The xi for all those lists are the same, on the good side.

Given that I'm working on a cluster, I tried to use ParallelTable to accelerate the calculation, with the code

```
(* tabvr is a list of 100*O(350,000) of (x, f(x)) pairs. For toy data of tabvr, see below *)

totpoint=Length[tabvr[[1]]];
wp=100;

LaunchKernels[100];
SetSharedVariable[tabvr];
vrpp$poly=ParallelTable[SetPrecision[InterpolatingPolynomial[Take[tabvr[[kk]],{i-3,i}],x]//Expand,wp]
          ,{kk,1,100},{i,4,totpoint}];
```

I requested 120 cores (5 nodes of 24 cores) and 400GB of memory. However, it turned out to be not enough and my job was killed as it goes beyond the memory limit. Moreover, the ParallelTable didn't seem to run as fast as I expected, as it takes ~50s for a single-core machine to process a single list, while it took about 2 hours before my job was terminated.

So, did I do anything wrong in this parallel calculation, or is such situation something I should expect for a parallel calculation? If it's the first case, what should I do to make the code work?

*Edit:*

If anyone want to actually play with the data, you may find a slice of the data [here](https://github.com/llxy7/Mathematica.SE) (the *vrpp86.dat* therein). You may just copy it 100 times to make a "complete" tabvr.

**A side question**

I also realized that, though I requested 5*24 cores, when I check the processor number

```
Print[$ProcessorCount];
```

I got the answer as 24 instead of 120. Does this mean that MMA's parallelization cannot work across different nodes?

---

### **Update**

As inspired by @Henrik Schumacher 's answer, I managed to shorten the running time of the code by a lot after using Compile

```
xgrid=tabvr[[1]];
ygrid=tabvr[[2]];
totpoint=Length[xgrid];
wp=100;

result0=SetPrecision[Table[CoefficientList[InterpolatingPolynomial[tabvr[[i-3;;i]],x],x],{i,4,totpoints}].{1,x,x^2,x^3}, wp]//AbsoluteTiming;
Print[result0[[1]]];

(*
to get the code working, mat in the following line should be replaced by the result of
D[CoefficientList[InterpolatingPolynomial[Array[{x[[#]], a[#]} &, 4], x], x], {Array[a, 4], 1}]//Simplify
*) 
calc$coeff2 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 1}}, mat.y, 
CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

result2 = (Table[SetPrecision[calc$coeff2[tabxgrid[[i - 3 ;; i]], ygrid[[i - 3 ;; i]]], wp], {i, 4, totpoints}].{1, x, x^2, x^3}) // AbsoluteTiming;
Print[result2[[1]]];
```

And I get the result

```
(* result0 *)
19.95942
(* result1 *)
2.976688
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Without (toy) data and without complete definitions, this is impossible to answer. So I expect this thread being closed soon, unless you _edit_ your post.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for the reminder. I added in a link to the toy data and modified the code a little bit. Now I guess one could play with it.

Answer (score 4):

Just don't use a cluster. You can do the full job on a costumer computer within a couple of seconds, at least if 15 digits of precision are sufficient. (I really wonder why you ask for 100 digits of precision.)

This is what I did: I downloaded the file `vrpp86.dat` into my home directory:

```
tabvr = ToPack[Join[##, 2] & @@ ConstantArray[ToPack@Import["~/vrpp86.dat"], 50]];

n = 10000;
x =.;
result0 = Table[
     CoefficientList[
      InterpolatingPolynomial[tabvr[[kk, i - 3 ;; i]] , x], x],
     {kk, 1, n}, {i, 4, Dimensions[tabvr][[2]]}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 38.6408

The combination of `CoefficientList`  and `InterpolatingPolynomial` is actually a linear operator acting on 4-vectors. We can generate the according matrix as follows:

```
A = Developer`ToPackedArray@N@
    D[
     CoefficientList[InterpolatingPolynomial[Array[a, 4], x], x],
     {Array[a, 4], 1}
     ];
```

This allows us to avoid all symbolic calculations and leads to a first speed-up:

```
result1 = Table[
     A . tabvr[[kk, i - 3 ;; i]],
     {kk, 1, n}, {i, 4, Dimensions[tabvr][[2]]}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 2.59673

Compiling this leads to a greater speed-up:

```
cf = Compile[{{tabvr, _Real, 2}, {A, _Real, 2}, {k, _Integer}},
   Block[{n, m},
    n = Dimensions[A][[2]] - 1;
    m = Dimensions[tabvr][[2]];
    Table[A . tabvr[[k, i - n ;; i]], {i, n + 1, m}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

result2 = cf[tabvr, A, Range[n]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.153785

And with a bit more effort, we can squeeze even more optimizations out  of the compiler:

```
cf2 = Block[{k, i, X, XX},
   XX = Table[ Compile`GetElement[X, k, l], {l, {i - 3, i - 2, i - 1, i}}];
   With[{code = A . XX},
    Compile[{{X, _Real, 2}, {k, _Integer}},
     Table[code, {i, 4, Dimensions[X][[2]]}],
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ]
    ]
   ];
result3 = cf2[tabvr, Range[n]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.028772

All variants have 15 digits of precision:

```
Max[Abs[1 - result0/result1]]
Max[Abs[1 - result0/result2]]
Max[Abs[1 - result0/result3]]
```

> 4.44089*10^-16
>
> 4.44089*10^-16
>
> 4.44089*10^-16

The compiled code is automatically parallelized. (This won't work on distributed systems.)

Timings were taken on my Quad Core Haswell CPU.

The full job is completed in less than a second:

```
fullresult = cf2[tabvr, Range[Length[tabvr]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.861428

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It's very helpful, but not yet exactly what I want, mainly due to that I didn't describe the data clear enough (question updated). The data I provided is not a one dimensional list but a list of (x, f(x)) pairs. In that case, is there a way to redefine the A matrix? I tried to promote it to a (N-3)*4*4 packed array with the x-grid, but then I got a warning saying there's not enough memory for the calculation.

Comment: It's very likely that you can compile also that. (I do not understand what you mean by "promote". Do not make any superfluous copies is all I can say.)

Comment: By saying "promote" I mean to increase the dimension of A. The current A matrix is 4-by-4 and generates the coefficient list of an interpolating polynomial on{{1, A[1]}, {2, A[2]}, {3, A[3]}, {4, A[4]}}. But to make it work on arbitrary {{x[i], y[i]}, {x[i+1], y[i+1]}, {x[i+2], y[i+2]}, {x[i+3], y[i+3]}} I think I have to work out the 4-by-4 A for any index i, which effective changes A to an (N-3)*4*4 array with N the length of my table.